# Merge and then sort columns of a dataframe based on the columns of the merging dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sorting, merge

I have two dataframes, both indexed with timestamps. I would like to preserve the order of the columns in the first dataframe that is merged.

For example:

```
#required packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# defining stuff
num_periods_1 = 11
num_periods_2 = 4

# create sample time series
dates1 = pd.date_range('1/1/2000 00:00:00', periods=num_periods_1, freq='10min')
dates2 = pd.date_range('1/1/2000 01:30:00', periods=num_periods_2, freq='10min')

column_names_1 = ['C', 'B', 'A']
column_names_2 = ['B', 'C', 'D']

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(num_periods_1, len(column_names_1)), index=dates1, columns=column_names_1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(num_periods_2, len(column_names_2)), index=dates2, columns=column_names_2)

df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=['_1', '_2'])
print("\nData Frame Three:\n", df3)
```

The above code generates two data frames the first with columns C, B, and A. The second dataframe has columns B, C, and D. The current output has the columns in the following order; C_1, B_1, A, B_2, C_2, D. What I want the columns from the output of the merge to be C_1, C_2, B_1, B_2, A_1, D_2. The order of the columns is preserved from the first data frame and any data similar to the second data frame is added next to the corresponding data.

Could there be a setting in merge or can I use sort_index to do this?

EDIT: Maybe a better way to phrase the sorting process would be to call it uncollated. Where each column is put together and so on.

Comment: Afraid there's no setting. Based on what criteria is the sorting done?

Comment: Well, I'm hoping that the criteria for sorting would be the order of the column names from column_names_1.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't D come first? By the way, why not just directly index the columns with your desired order?

Comment: Well when you merge the two data frames it becomes one after the other. (i.e. ['C_1', 'B_1', 'A', 'B_2', 'C_2', 'D']). I want to rearrange it so that each column is "paired" with its counter part (i.e. ['C_1', 'C_2', 'B_1', 'B_2', 'A', 'D']). technically I could just code it that way for this sample code but I want it to be more automated.

Comment: What do you think about using a ordered dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an `OrderedDict`, as you [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46820152/merge-and-then-sort-columns-of-a-dataframe-based-on-the-columns-of-the-merging-d?noredirect=1#comment80619977_46820152).

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import chain

c = df3.columns.tolist()
o = OrderedDict()

for x in c:
    o.setdefault(x.split('_')[0], []).append(x)

c = list(chain.from_iterable(o.values()))
df3 = df3[c]
```

---

An alternative that involves extracting the prefixes and *then* calling `sorted` on the index.

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/46839182/4909087
p = [s[0] for s in c]
c = sorted(c, key=lambda x: (p.index(x[0]), x))
df = df[c]
```

Comment: Nice one! That works perfect for this. Just thinking of other instances now though. How could this be implemented if concat was used instead of merge? concat would re order the columns right away. So this would have to be done with a list of columns from each data frame.

Comment: @MooseDrool `concat` came to mind first. Unfortunately, you cannot specify suffixes in `concat`, so you'll have to call `.add_suffix` before concatenating. This also means `A` and `D` will receive suffixes, unless you  can somehow control that. You'd concat along the first axis, by the way.

Comment: Oh yeah. Adding a suffic to A and D wouldn't hurt it.