# Combine list elements by suffix

Tags: python, list

Given two lists with suffixes:

```
l1 = ['C_1', 'B_1', 'A']
l2 = ['B_2', 'C_2', 'D']
```

I want to combine them like this:

```
['C_1', 'C_2', 'B_1', 'B_2', 'A', 'D']
```

Elements are to be combined with `l1` as the anchor. This means, if `C_*` comes before `B_*` in `l1`, the same ordering will be preserved in the output. Furthermore, elements with the same prefix `C_*` will be grouped together, in increasing order of suffix. Elements with a suffix are placed in the order in which they appear, as you see above.

You can assume that all elements in `l1` have suffix `_1`, and all elements in `l2` have suffix `_2`.

I've tried this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import chain

o = OrderedDict()
for x in l1 + l2:
    o.setdefault(x.split('_')[0], []).append(x) 

result = list(chain.from_iterable(o.values()))
```

Which works, but was wondering if there were any more succinct ways of doing this.

Edit:

The suffix is just a stand in for which list that element appears in. Say I have `C_1` from `l1`, and `C_2` from `l2`, then `C_*` elements appear based on which was in `l1` and which was in `l2`, in the final list (so, it'd be `... C_1, C_2...`).

Furthermore, all elements in `l1` and `l2` are unique wrt each other and themselves. Hope that helps.

Comment: does order of `l2` matter? not in your sample data as there's only one element without suffix/group from `l1`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The `l1` ordering is the anchor here. The ordering of `l2` elements wrt each other in the final list doesn't matter.

Comment: You mean *numerical* suffix, or *lexicographical* suffix?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Really, the suffix is just a stand in for which list that element appears in. Say I have C_1 from l1, and C_2, from l2, then C_ elements appear based on which was in l1 and which was in l2, in the final list (so, it'd be ... C_1, C_2...) . I hope that clears things up!

Comment: You can also assume the suffix will always be numerical, if that helps.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Code Review. As per https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312975/where-is-the-right-place-to-ask-for-code-improvements.

Comment: @mkrieger1 No, I don't want my code improved, I want to know if there are different ways of doing this.

Comment: I could also argue "unclear what you're asking" or "too broad" or "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: @mkrieger1 I don't see how you'd have valid points for any of those arguments.

Comment: My point is that I find it unlikely that someone in the future has a problem for which answers to this question would be a solution. At least in my opinion the question should be more generic to be useful.

Comment: @mkrieger1 https://stackoverflow.com/q/46820152/4909087 I wanted a better solution to this answer. Stop the hyper nitpicks please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Alex answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46838487/combine-list-elements-by-suffix/46839182#46839182) is short, but uses `list.index` which has `O(n)` complexity.

I would suggest a small adaptation with building `p` as a dictionary, reversing the iteration to emulate how `index` works (else last indexes are returned when there are more than 1 occurrence).

In that case, the sort key function uses dict lookup instead, much faster:

```
l1 = ['C_1', 'B_1', 'A']
l2 = ['B_2', 'C_2', 'D']

p = {s[0]:i for i,s in reversed(list(enumerate(l1 + l2)))}
print(sorted(l1 + l2, key=lambda x: (p[x[0]], x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

With `itertools.groupby()` and `sorted()` functions:

```
import itertools

l1 = ['C_1', 'B_1', 'A']
l2 = ['B_2', 'C_2', 'D']
l1_len = len(l1)
groups_gen = (list(g) for k,g in itertools.groupby(sorted(l1+l2), key=lambda x: x[0] or '_' not in x))
result = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(sorted(groups_gen,
              key=lambda x: l1.index(x[0]) if x[0] in l1 else l1_len)))

print(result)
```

The output:

```
['C_1', 'C_2', 'B_1', 'B_2', 'A', 'D']
```

Comment: Wow, that seems more complicated than the ordered dict solution :p

Comment: Martjin commented on that method on one similar answer of mine (now deleted): using itertools.groupby with sorted list is `O(n*2 * log(n))`. Concise, but probably slower

Comment: yes, gentlemen, I realize that this could be probably slower that potential solutions using some `Mapping` objects. But that's the way I could achieve the needed aggregation/grouping.  Another alternative solutions with better performance are welcome

Answer (score 1):

Sort all the elements by the index at which their prefix appears in `l1`, using the rest of the string to break ties:

```
p = [s[0] for s in l1 + l2]
print(sorted(l1 + l2, key=lambda x: (p.index(x[0]), x)))
```

`p` uses prefixes from both `l1` and `l2` so that `p.index(x[0])` doesn't raise an error.

Comment: This seems like a really nice alternative. Thanks.

Comment: it won't sort the remaining items. For example, l1 = ['C_1', 'B_1', 'A']
l2 = ['B_2', 'C_2', 'F', 'D'] will lead to ['C_1', 'C_2', 'B_1', 'B_2', 'A', 'F', 'D'] but not sure if that's desirable for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do by this method

```
l1 = ['C_1', 'B_1', 'A']
l2 = ['B_2', 'C_2', 'D']
```

First select all first common words items

```
new=[y for item in l1 for item2 in l2 for y in  [item] + [item2] if item[0]==item2[0]]
```

Notice i am using extend in list comprehension above.

Now just find which item is remaining other than first letter common items:

```
    for item1 in l2:
        for item2 in l1:
            if item1 not in new:
                new.append(item1)

            elif item2 not in new:
                new.append(item2)


print(new)
```